# ElasticSearch get _id

Tags: java, elasticsearch, get

How can I retrieve the _id elasticsearch field information using Java API? I know I can see this information with head plugin, looking to documents, but it's not necessary for me.

I'm developing a Java project, and all commands, like update, delete, require this _id value. But how can I get it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When executing a search, you get back an object SearchResponse. By calling the method getHits() you get back a list of objects of type SearchHit. This object has a method id().

```
SearchResponse searchResponse =  client.prepareSearch().setQuery(matchAllQuery()).get();
for (SearchHit hit : searchResponse.getHits()) {
  String yourId = hit.id();
}
```

Comment: String yourId = hit.getId();  ->

For new version of elastic